# XSD Schema element can be either of Two Types

Tags: java, xml, xsd, jaxb, schema

I've been looking around and is there really no easy way to have an element be two possible types? I have tried the following workarounds.

```
<xs:element name="food">
  <xs:complexType>
     <xs:choice>
       <xs:element name="meat" type="meatFoods"/>
       <xs:element name="veggies" type="veggieFoods"/>
     </xs:choice>
  </xs:complexType>
</xs:element>
```

```
food cannot have character [children], because the type's content type is element-only.
```

And:

```
<xs:choice>
  <xs:sequence>
    <xs:element name="food" type="meatFoods"/>
  </xs:sequnce>
  <xs:sequence>
    <xs:element name="food" type="veggieFoods"/>
  </xs:sequence>
</xs:choice>
```

Gives error about same name different types

And:

```
<xs:complexType name="MeatOrVeggies">
  <xs:choice>
    <xs:element name="meat" type="meatFoods"/>
    <xs:element name="veggies" type="veggieFoods"/>
  </xs:choice>
</xs:complexType>
```

```
<xs:element name="food" type="MeatOrVeggies"/>
```

```
food cannot have character [children], because the type's content type is element-only.
```

These all throw some kind of error. The last one gives food is an element, and no child allowed error, and the second gives "Multiple elements with name "food", with different types appear in the model group."

This XSD is the payload for a java payload object, which has:
`FoodInterface food`. Meat and Veggies are enums of that interface, like so:

```
public enum Meat implements FoodInterface{
   Chicken,
   Beef,
   Pork
}
```

Meat/Veggie Enum in Schema:

```
<xs:simpleType name="meatFoods">
  <xs:restriction base="xs:string">
    <xs:enumeration value="chicken"/>
    <xs:enumeration value="beef"/>
    <xs:enumeration value="pork"/>
  </xs:restriction>
</xs:simpleType>

<xs:simpleType name="veggieFoods">
  <xs:restriction base="xs:string">
    <xs:enumeration value="spinach"/>
    <xs:enumeration value="broccoli"/>
    <xs:enumeration value="tomato"/>
  </xs:restriction>
</xs:simpleType>
Thanks in advance.
```

Comment: What's your XML?

Comment: @zx485 Shoot this is from Java I should've mentioned. The food element is of type foodInterface and can be either meat or veggies, which are both enums that implement the food interface.

Comment: @zx485 added some java code for possible clarity. I don't have any XML being produced right now because of errors.

Comment: @phevib, it seems that XSD union will have you covered.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the types are simple types, use a union type.

If the types are complex types, then use xs:choice: but the resulting content model must be unambiguous (that is, the first element you encounter must tell you which branch of the choice to take).

Since you haven't told us what the two types meatFoods and veggieFoods are, it's hard to be more specific in answering. You also haven't been explicit about what errors you are getting.

Comment: Updated post with meat/veggie defs and errors. Could you elaborate on union types? If I only want one of the two types, wouldn't union give both.

Comment: If A allows values "x", "y", and "z", and B allows "p", "q", and "r", then the union type with member types A and B allows any one of "x", "y", "z",  "p", "q", and "r". (Of course the value spaces can also overlap, but that's not relevant to your use case.)

Comment: Oh wow I realized I was so focused on how to choose one or the other, that I didn't realize I can just put both in the pool. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

*"...The union element defines a simple type as a collection (union) of values from specified simple data types..."*
Check it out here: https://www.w3schools.com/xml/el_union.asp

Comment: I don't want both. The food element (from Java) is an interface and will only be Meat OR Veggies, not both. I want the schema to be able to do the corresponding one.

Comment: Michael Kay replied a little after and I realized that you were correct as well. Thanks.